# LLVM function hoisting best approach

Tags: llvm

I would like to have function hoisting in my language, so something like this should work,

```
foo();

void foo() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

What is the best approach for that with LLVM? Is there a pass that can be used? Would I need to write my own pass? Would it be easier to rearrange the AST before getting to LLVM?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What hoisting means in this context?

Comment: (Assuming you mean calling functions before they are defined:) LLVM doesn't really care about the order of definitions in your language. But in order to generate a function call, you will need to have a complete prototype (not just for LLVM, but typically also for other tasks of your frontend like type checking).